# What to include in .ignore in GAE Java Web Application project?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, google-app-engine

When building a GAE web application project using Eclipse, are there any files within the project folder which I should not upload to git? I.e. anything to include in my `.gitignore` file?

The top levels of the project structure looks like this

```
 src
   --com
   --META-INF
   --log4j.properties
war
   -- WEB-INF
         --classes
              -- lots more stuff..
         --lib
         --logging properties
         --appengine-web
         --web.xml
.classpath
.project
```

etc, with a lot more stuff in the lower levels.

Anything that would contain sensitive info and be dangerous to upload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that a file called `.ignore` won't do anything to Git. Ignore files are usually called `.gitignore`.

[`gitignore.io`](https://www.gitignore.io/) [suggests](https://www.gitignore.io/api/appengine) this for Java and AppEngine:

```
# Created by https://www.gitignore.io

### AppEngine ###
# Google App Engine generated folder
appengine-generated/


### Java ###
*.class

# Mobile Tools for Java (J2ME)
.mtj.tmp/

# Package Files #
*.jar
*.war
*.ear

# virtual machine crash logs, see http://www.java.com/en/download/help/error_hotspot.xml
hs_err_pid*
```

`gitignore.io` gets its ignore suggestions [from](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Java.gitignore) [GitHub](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/AppEngine.gitignore).